MacTeX on macOS: how to get the SyncTeX library?
I have MacTeX installed on macOS, and an executable called synctex is already in my PATH. However, I cannot find a file named libsynctex.so anywhere on the system, which is what I need to compile some code.
sudo tlmgr install synctex shows that synctex is already installed. How to get the library?
If I want to compile the Gummi editor which need synctex, how to let the ./configure script find it? This includes getting synctex_parser.h header.

From tlmgr info --list synctex, the synctex package only provides a bin/universal-darwin/synctex binary file.

@muzimuzhiZ So if I want to compile the Gummi editor which need synctex, how to let the ./configure script find it? This includes getting synctex_parser.h.

It seems Homebrew has it available (brew install synctex). See also https://github.com/alexandervdm/gummi/issues/175.

@Marijn It's provided by a third-party tap: brew tap zegervdv/zathura. And it installs libsynctex.dylib.

There's no guarantee something provided by brew will be compatible with TeX Live. You might get mismatching versions or whatever. I am not sure - because it is too long since I had a Mac - but I don't think gummi should be looking for a .so at all. Macs did not used to use .so, but .dylib.

@cfr .so or .dylib. Both are valid extensions for a shared library.

@MaJoad Good to know. But configure should look for both on Macs, I guess, since I assume .dylib is still no uncommon in that case?
